# Run-time error '13' : Deleting data from a merged cell

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have no experience with VBA and have been trying to google my way through some functionality I want. The current goal is to hide a row based on the entry of another cell. This part works, but if the data is deleted I get the error. The code is below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Activate
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("U8:Y8"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        Select Case Target.Value
            Case Is = "Owner": Rows("11:11").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case Is = "Renter":  Rows("11:11").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case Is = "":  Rows("11:11").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End Select
                                              
End If

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("U8:Y8"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        Select Case Target.Value
            Case Is = "Renter": Rows("18:18").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case Is = "Owner":  Rows("18:18").EntireRow.Hidden = False      
            Case Is = "":  Rows("18:18").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End Select
End If

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("G22:K22"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        Select Case Target.Value
            Case Is = "Mail": Rows("23:23").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case Is = "E-Billing":  Rows("23:23").EntireRow.Hidden = False        
            Case Is = "":  Rows("23:23").EntireRow.Hidden = False        
        End Select
                
End If

End Sub
```

Originally the Range was just "U8" and "G22" and I thought if I included the full range of each merged area it would work, but no.

Comment: You mention merged ranges but haven't told us where they are on the sheet.  You're testing for U8:Y8 twice - is that intentional?  Also `Range(Target.Address)` is the same as just `Target`

Comment: If `Target` is a multi-cell range, then its `.Value` is a 2D array that can't be compared directly to a `String`.

Comment: `Case Is = "Owner"` ----> `Case "Owner"`, and so on. Also all the instances of  `.EntireRow` are redundant and can be removed.

Comment: Btw, the value in a merged cell is present in the topmost, leftmost cell, so you would just check `U8` and `G22`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! The merged cells are U8:Y8 and G22:K22 (the targets). My intention was that if the entry is "Owner" then row 11 is hidden. If the entry is "Renter" I need row 18 hidden - which is why the same merged cell is referenced twice.

Comment: When entering a value into a merged cell, it triggers the Change event with a single-cell `Target` (Target.Cells.CountLarge=1), but when deleting that same value, it triggers with a multi-cell `Target` (Target.Cells.CountLarge=5), so you need to account for that in your event handling code...

Answer (score 2):

When *entering* a value into a merged cell, it triggers the `Change` event with a single-cell `Target` (ie. `Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1`), but when *deleting* a value from a merged cell, it triggers with a multi-cell `Target` (in this case, `Target.Cells.CountLarge = 5`), so you need to account for that in your event handling code.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim v, c As Range
    
    Debug.Print Target.Address, Target.Cells.CountLarge, TypeName(Target.Value)
    
    'Handle the multi-cell Target when a value is deleted from a merged cell
    If Target.Cells(1).MergeArea.Address = Target.Address Then 'is Target a merged cell?
        Set c = Target.Cells(1) 'get the first cell in the mergearea
    Else
        Set c = Target 'regular case...
    End If
    If c.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Select Case c.Address(False, False)
        Case "U8"
            Select Case c.Value
                Case "Owner"
                    Me.Rows(11).Hidden = True
                    Me.Rows(18).Hidden = False
                Case "Renter"
                    Me.Rows(11).Hidden = False
                    Me.Rows(18).Hidden = True
                Case ""
                    Me.Rows(11).Hidden = False
                    Me.Rows(18).Hidden = False
            End Select
        Case "G22"
            Select Case c.Value
                Case "Mail": Me.Rows(23).Hidden = True
                Case "E-Billing", "": Me.Rows(23).Hidden = False
            End Select
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: There was definitely no way I was googling my way into that answer. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Well that enter vs delete thing was new to me also, so I did learn something from that...

Comment: In each case are there only 3 possible values?  U8: Owner/Renter/{empty}     G22: Mail/E-billing/{empty}   ?

Comment: Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help anyone else coming along later with a similar problem.